# Java RandomAccessFile modificar un registro de un archivo txt

Tags: java, archivo, random, registro

Tengo un archivo con registros de empleados y debo poder modificarlos usando RandomAccessFile. Más o menos lo he conseguido, salvo porque cuando el nuevo registro es mas corto, me encuentro añadiendo espacios y cuando es mas largo, me encuentro con que me como parte de la linea siguiente.

Imagino que la solucion pasa por...

1. coger el registro y guardar el resto del archivo de ahi hacia adelante en un buffer temporal
2. eliminar tanto el registro deseado como todo lo que le siga
3. escribir mi registro al final del archivo
4. añadir lo que haya guardado en el buffer temporal

El problema es que no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

Mi código aqui...

```
private static void actividad7(){
    try {
        String rutaCarpeta = ".\\carpetaEjercicio";
        String nombreArchivo = "\\FichTextoActividad6b.txt";
        File archivo = new File(rutaCarpeta + nombreArchivo);
        String[] str = {"ID: 1, Apellido: FERNANDEZ, Departamento: 10 Salario:1050.45", 
                            "ID: 2, Apellido: RAMOS Departamento: 20 Salario:1350.6", 
                            "ID: 3, Apellido: GIL, Departamento: 10 Salario:1285.20", 
                            "ID: 4, Apellido: LOPEZ, Departamento: 10 Salario:1530.17",
                            "ID: 5, Apellido: PONS, Departamento: 30 Salario:1427.65",
                            "ID: 6, Apellido: BARTUAL, Departamento: 30 Salario:1783.7",
                            "ID: 7, Apellido: HERNANDEZ, Departamento: 20 Salario:1130.55"};
        int[] longitud = new int[str.length];
        //El archivo es creado linea a linea con el texto contenido en "str" en una actividad anterior
        if(!archivo.exists()){
            System.out.println("No es encuentra el archivo. Ejecuta la actividad '6b'");
        }else{
            //guardo la longitud de cada una de las lineas
            for(int i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
                longitud[i] = str[i].length();
            }
            boolean encontrado = false;
            System.out.println("Introduce la ID del empleado que deseas buscar");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            String id = sc.nextLine();
            //Aqui no voy a comprobar si es un numero, porque me da igual para esta actividad
            System.out.println("Ahora introduce el nuevo salario");
            String salario = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ahora introduce el nuevo departamento");
            String departamento = sc.nextLine();


            //Esto es lo que me va a permitir encontrar el registro
            String palabraClave = "ID: "+id;
            
            String lineaNew = "asd";
            String lineaOld = "asd"
            int delStrSize = 0;
            
            //Accedo al archivo en modo lectura para saber si existe el registro que se busca
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r");
            String linea = raf.readLine();
            while(linea != null){
                if(linea.contains(palabraClave)){
                    //Construyo el nuevo registro con el salario y el dept introducidos
                    String partes1[] = linea.split("Departamento: ");
                    partes1[0] += "Departamento: ";
                    String[] partes2 = partes1[1].split(" Salario:");
                    partes2[0] = departamento;
                    partes2[1] = " Salario:"+salario;
                    encontrado = true;
                    lineaNew = partes1[0] + partes2[0] + partes2[1];
                    lineaOld = linea;
                    //A PARTIR DE AQUI VIENE EL LIO                        
                    //Averiguo si la linea nueva es mas corta que la vieja
                    delStrSize = lineaOld.length() - lineaNew.length();
                    //Y si es asi, añado espacios hasta que midan lo mismo y asi "no se nota"
                    if(delStrSize > 0){
                        for(int i = 0; i < delStrSize; i++){
                            lineaNew += " ";
                        }
                    }
                }
                linea = raf.readLine();
            }
            raf.close();
            if(!encontrado){
                System.out.println("No se encontró al empleado con la ID: "+id);
            //Ahora accedo en modo lectura/escritura
            }else{
                raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "rw");
                linea = raf.readLine();
                while(linea != null){
                    //Si encuentro el registro que busco...
                    if(linea.contains(lineaOld)){
                        //Me pongo al principio de la linea
                        raf.seek(0);
                        //Y escribo la nueva linea
                        //PERO ESTO ME SUPONE 2 PROBLEMAS:
                        //  - si la linea nueva es mas corta he añadido espacios que no quiero añadir
                        //  - y si es mas larga, se come parte de la linea siguiente
                        raf.writeBytes(lineaNew);
                    }
                    linea = raf.readLine();
                }
                raf.close();
            }
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error I/O: "+e);
    }
}
```

Un saludo!
G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente solución usa un archivo temporal para actualizar la línea que se desea reemplazar, luego el archivo original se reemplaza por el temporal:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                actividad7();
    }

    private static void actividad7() {
        try {
            String rutaCarpeta = "/";
            String nombreArchivo = "archivo.txt";

            File archivo = new File(rutaCarpeta + nombreArchivo);
            String[] str = {
                    "ID: 1, Apellido: FERNANDEZ, Departamento: 10 Salario:1050.45",
                    "ID: 2, Apellido: RAMOS Departamento: 20 Salario:1350.6",
                    "ID: 3, Apellido: GIL, Departamento: 10 Salario:1285.20",
                    "ID: 4, Apellido: LOPEZ, Departamento: 10 Salario:1530.17",
                    "ID: 5, Apellido: PONS, Departamento: 30 Salario:1427.65",
                    "ID: 6, Apellido: BARTUAL, Departamento: 30 Salario:1783.7",
                    "ID: 7, Apellido: HERNANDEZ, Departamento: 20 Salario:1130.55"};
            int[] longitud = new int[str.length];
            //El archivo es creado linea a linea con el texto contenido en "str" en una actividad anterior
            if (!archivo.exists()) {
                System.out.println("No es encuentra el archivo. Ejecuta la actividad '6b'");
            } else {
                //guardo la longitud de cada una de las lineas
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                    longitud[i] = str[i].length();
                }
                boolean encontrado = false;
                System.out.println("Introduce la ID del empleado que deseas buscar");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String id = sc.nextLine();
                //Aqui no voy a comprobar si es un numero, porque me da igual para esta actividad
                System.out.println("Ahora introduce el nuevo salario");
                String salario = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ahora introduce el nuevo departamento");
                String departamento = sc.nextLine();


                //Esto es lo que me va a permitir encontrar el registro
                String palabraClave = "ID: " + id;

                String lineaNew = "asd";
                String lineaOld = "asd";
                int delStrSize = 0;

                // variable para guardar la posición en la que se encontró la línea
                int lineaPos = 1;

                //Accedo al archivo en modo lectura para saber si existe el registro que se busca
                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r");
                String linea = raf.readLine();
                while (linea != null) {
                    if (linea.contains(palabraClave)) {
                        //Construyo el nuevo registro con el salario y el dept introducidos
                        String[] partes1 = linea.split("Departamento: ");
                        partes1[0] += "Departamento: ";
                        String[] partes2 = partes1[1].split(" Salario:");
                        partes2[0] = departamento;
                        partes2[1] = " Salario:" + salario;
                        encontrado = true;
                        lineaNew = partes1[0] + partes2[0] + partes2[1];
                        lineaOld = linea;
                        //A PARTIR DE AQUI VIENE EL LIO
                        //Averiguo si la linea nueva es mas corta que la vieja
                        delStrSize = lineaOld.length() - lineaNew.length();
                        //Y si es asi, añado espacios hasta que midan lo mismo y asi "no se nota"
                        if (delStrSize > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < delStrSize; i++) {
                                lineaNew += " ";
                            }
                        }
                        // terminar el ciclo si ya se encontró la línea
                        break;
                    }
                    linea = raf.readLine();
                    // incrementar la posición
                    lineaPos++;
                }

                raf.close();

                if (!encontrado) {
                    System.out.println("No se encontró al empleado con la ID: " + id);
                    //Ahora accedo en modo lectura/escritura
                } else {

                    // ya se sabe que la línea se encontró y está en la posición
                    // lineaPos

                    // crear archivo temporal

                    File f = new File("/archivoTemp.txt");
                    f.createNewFile();

                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);

                    // abrir archivo en modo lectura
                    raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r");

                    int pos = 1;

                    linea = raf.readLine();

                    // recorrer el archivo original
                    while (linea != null) {
                        // si estamos en la línea que se va a reemplazar
                        // entonces lineaAEscribir será igual a lineaNew
                        String lineaAEscribir = (pos == lineaPos) ? lineaNew : linea;
                        // se escribe la lína en el archivo temporal
                        writer.write(lineaAEscribir + "\n");

                        linea = raf.readLine();
                        pos++;
                    }
                    
                    raf.close();
                    writer.close();
                    // se elimina el archivo anterior
                    archivo.delete();
                    // se renombra el nuevo archivo
                    f.renameTo(archivo);


                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error I/O: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta. Perfect!